# Add to another user array Parse Android

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

In Parse I have another column in the User table known as 'Friends' which is an array. From my current user I am trying to add to another user's friends array.

I have tried:

```
//buddy = a string of the other person's username
//to add to CURRENT user's array (this is working)
UserList.user.addUnique("Friends", buddy);
UserList.user.saveEventually();

    //this is to add to another user's array (NOT WORKING)
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("username", buddy);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // The query was successful.
                for (ParseObject friend : objects) {
                    friend.addUnique("Friends",UserList.user.getUsername());
                    friend.saveEventually();
                }
            } else {
                // Something went wrong.
                Log.d("Username", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Write a method in a java that passes data to the cloud, and calls the function on the cloud by its name:

```
// the passes to the cloud is stored on HashMap
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// user's name to add the buddy to it
params.put("username", username);    
// buddy's name to pass to the cloud    
params.put("buddy", buddy);
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("addBuddyToFriendsList", params, new FunctionCallback<String>(){
    public void done(String result, ParseException e){
    // e==null means no errors in running the function
       if(e==null){
          System.out.println(result);
       }else{
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
    }
});
```

Ok, and now let's write the function to be used in the cloud (assuming you know how to deploy functions on the cloud):

**[EDITED]**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addBuddyToFriendsList", function (request, response){
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);    
query.find({
    success: function(user) {
        // query.find returns an array.....            
        user[0].addUnique("Friends", request.params.buddy);
        user[0].save(null, {
           success: function(success){
              response.success();
           }, 
           error: function (error){
               response.error(error);
           }
        });
        }, 
        error: function(object, error) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: After much debugging I still get the error, "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addUnique'".

Comment: Hey buddy, just edited, you know, sometimes working with js can be confusing cause you can't see your compiler errors right away. Anyways, query.find method returns array, and since we have one result, we call the first place of the result, user[0]. I hope this one's gonna work, good luck.

Comment: When you 'callFunctionInBackground' it cannot parse the JSON into a string ("org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String"). How would I return a string? or another solution? Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Glad to help always. So now it's working? You can define in the FunctionCallback, what type to receive, you can change <String> to <JSONObject> , and change the type of the parameter in "done" method to JSONObject, try that and let me know. And that is assuming you know how to handle the json object back in java.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
query.whereEqualTo("username", buddy);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // The query was successful.
            for (ParseObject friend : objects) {
                friend.addUnique("Friends",UserList.user.getUsername());
                friend.saveEventually();
            }
        } else {
            // Something went wrong.
            Log.d("Username", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to call that class in different way then you did, I referred to it like a normal class. Usually this way works for me.
The thing is with "ParseUser" type is limited, for security reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not add it to the other person's array :(  Any other method that could be used instead since the ParseUser class is limited?

Comment: Yes. You can do it through the cloud, you can use master key - > "Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()" . It's not a problem at all, if you're having trouble let me know i'll share a code with you. check this in mean while: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions

Comment: could you help a bit.. I tried using beforeSave function but nothing happened

Comment: I just posted a solution code for you, it should work. When you work with cloud code, you get logs in your parse.com interface, use that, it's very helpful to see what went wrong.